# how to prevent accidental factory reset in android?

Tags: factory-reset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I disable or password protect my device's 'factory reset' function?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18935/how-can-i-disable-or-password-protect-my-devices-factory-reset-function)

is there any way to prevent the factory reset? like password protection? I basically need to protect my phone from resetting when it lands on thief's hand.