# Is a factory reset from recovery different from one started in the OS?

Tags: samsung, recovery-mode, factory-reset

```
Galaxy S4 I9505 on 5.1 Stock
```

Handset has stability issues and I can't find a clear answer if a factory reset started in the OS runs the same process as one started via recovery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is only one difference — on Lollipop and higher, a factory reset from Settings will remove [Factory Reset Protection](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/109157/1465) from your device.  It will ask you to enter your device and/or Google Account password in order to verify that you are the owner of the device.  Resets from Recovery do not remove FRP since they can be initiated by anyone, such as a phone thief.

Comment: Perfect, diagnostically identical for me so. Thanks.